# Write this pseudocode in python

Tags: python, algorithm, pseudocode, insertion-sort

I am trying to convert this pseudocode into python code

```
1 for j = 2 to A.length
2     i=1
3        while A[j]>A[i]
4             i = i+1
5        key = A[j]
6        for k = to j -i - 1
7           A[j-k] = A[j-k-1]
8        A[i] = key
```

The program says that i have to take 10 inputs and display it in the sorted array using Insertion sort algorithm Here's what i done at the moment i'm stuck at line 6 how do i convert that to python code

```
A= [int(i) for i in input ('Enter Number').spilt()]

    for j in range(2, len(A)):
        i = 1:
            while A[j] > A[i]:
                i = i+1
            key = A[j]
            for:#?
                A[j-k] = A[j-k-1]
            A[i] = key
```

Comment: Some key steps appear somewhat different from this insertion sort in Python: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-insertion-sort/

Comment: That loop statement in `6` (so the pseudocode already) is incomplete, and the subsequent indexing `[j-k(-1)]` seems overcomplicated. If it comes from a book/course/website/etc., you may want to consider switching to another one.

Comment: What does `for k = to j -i - 1` mean?

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is something missing in that line 6:

> ```
> for k = to j -i - 1
> ```

It should read:

```
for k = 0 to j - i - 1
```

There are a few things to bear in mind when converting to Python:

- In Python the first list element is at index 0, not index 1 as is the case in that pseudo code. So that means you need to subtract one at several places (where it concerns `i` and `j`).
- Similarly, the `range` function's second argument (the "end" of the range) is a value that is *not* included in the range, while in the pseudo code, what follows `to` *is* included.

So here is how you could translate the code:

```
A= [int(i) for i in input ('Enter Number').split()]

for j in range(1, len(A)):
    i = 0 # zero-based index
    while A[j] > A[i]:
        i = i+1
    key = A[j]
    for k in range(0, j-i):
        A[j-k] = A[j-k-1]
    A[i] = key
```

As stated in comments, the loop on `k` seems overly complex. It could just be:

```
for k in range(j, i, -1):
    A[k] = A[k-1]
```

And a bit more pythonic would be to replace that `for` loop with:

```
A[i+1:j+1] = A[i:j]
```

Finally, the outer loop can take the index and value (`key`) with `enumerate`, which saves a few repetitive list look-ups in the form of `A[j]`:

```
for j, key in enumerate(A):
    i = 0
    while val > A[i]:
        i = i+1
    A[i+1:j+1] = A[i:j]
    A[i] = key
```

With this `for` loop, you get one more iteration (with `j == 0`) which does nothing really, so you may decide to use the original loop.